# Magento's Prototype.js is Conflict with Fabric.js

Tags: magento, fabricjs

I am using fabric canvas in Magento, But fabric is conflicting with Magento's prototype.

It's showing the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function      prototype.js:5734**
fire @ prototype.js:5734
Object.extend._methodized @ prototype.js:438
fireContentLoadedEvent @ prototype.js:5820
Uncaught Error: Could not initialize `canvas` element fabric.js:5655
(anonymous function) @ fabric.js:5655
(anonymous function) @ fabric.js:7235
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I use FabricJS in Magento 1.6.2 without an conflicts with Prototype.  Without seeing more of your Fabric code it's hard to say where the error is coming from...  I'd start by stripping out Fabric code to the very basics and see if you get the same errors.  If not, start adding pieces of code until you can isolate where the issue is - it could be something as simple as a missing semicolon or closing bracket that is breaking scripts beyond it in the page.

Comment: I am using fabric 1.4.0 with prototype version 1.7, It is conflicting at line number 1984 in fabric and in prototype at 5734, just above some line there is element declaration with $ sign. May this be reason?